# primeNG caption and header templates show even when table is empty?

Tags: angular, primeng

I tried hiding caption and header with an ngIf, but I am still getting a table row outputted. Any tips, how to completely hide caption and header if table has no values?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtjfo5?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

source blitz with data : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poukrn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in a couple of ways.

##### Using CSS

```css
.ui-table-caption, .ui-table-thead {
  display: none;
}
```

You might have to use `ng-deep` for this.

##### Empty templates

If you pass an empty template for the caption and headers, you can get rid of them

```html
<ng-template pTemplate="caption"></ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header"></ng-template>
```